# File compare incl wildcards for variables with Robot Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

Im trying to compare the page source with Robot Framework. I added the robotframework-difflibrary for extra compare, however I can not send a wildcard for check. 
In my page source there is always the date and time which will never be the same. So my result will always be false because the date / time part is different.
Is it possible to let Robot Framework to ignore some parts of the HTML?

Example of time / date HTML tag:

td class="r">12:43:01

td class="r" width="10%">8-8-2017

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to cause that keyword to ignore parts of the HTML. You will  have to write your own keyword, or modify the html before doing the compare.